# how to change the label text when Entry control IsFocused becomes true using trigger in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to create a trigger for the Entry control which will change the text of the Label control when the Entry control get's the focus and again change label text to default when Entry control loss the focus.

I have done the below code, but this changes the Label text when text is entered in Entry control but I want to change it when the Entry control get the focus not on text change.

```
<Label
    x:Name="HeaderText"
    Text="Lets start here">
    <Label.Triggers>
        <MultiTrigger TargetType="Label">
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference TextEntry},
                        Path=Text.Length,
                        Converter={StaticResource dataHasBeenEntered}}"
                        Value="true" />
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="Enter Name" />
        </MultiTrigger>
    </Label.Triggers>
</Label>
```

**MultiTriggerConverter**

```
public class MultiTriggerConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
    object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ((int)value > 0) // length > 0 ?
            return true;            // some data has been entered
        else
            return false;            // input is empty
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to do it via MVVM ?

Comment: no, I'm asking how to do it on IsFocused event of Entry control using trigger

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.visualelement.focused?view=xamarin-forms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simply use the IsFocused property like:

```
<StackLayout>
    <Entry x:Name="TextEntry" />
    <!-- Place new controls here -->
    <Label x:Name="HeaderText" Text="Lets start here">
        <Label.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" 
                         Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference TextEntry},
                         Path=IsFocused}"
                         Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="Enter Name" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Label.Triggers>
    </Label>
</StackLayout>
```

Moreover, you can also use the placeholder to indicate what user need to put:

```
<Entry x:Name="TextEntry" Placeholder="Enter Name"/>
```

Hope it helps.